# Проблемы с понимаем оператора if

Tags: python, логические-выражения

Я на начальном этапе изучения и у меня сложности с пониманием работы оператора `if`. Вот код:

```
if True:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

(из самоучителя)
Во -первых, я не понимаю, что вообще значит `True`. Я понимаю, когда есть переменная, и мы ее приравниваем к какому-то значению, но здесь просто `True` - что именно `True`? Напечатать `True`?
Во-вторых,  когда я ввожу все что угодно кроме `True` ( и `False`, потому что когда ввожу `False`, выводит `False`) выводит ошибку: `NameError: name '...' is not defined`.

Как мне добиться того, чтобы он выводил `False` на любое значение кроме `True`?

Comment: Вы рановато взялись за операторы выбора, попробуйте внимательно перечитать все, что было "до". "Оператор if else позволяет определить программисту действие, когда условие истинно и альтернативное действие, когда условие ложно"

Comment: а можете посоветовать ресурс, по которому изучать? я учу по самоучителю, там оператор if  - одна из самых начальных тем, до этого только описывается синтаксис и hello world . как наиболее оптимально и последовательно изучать?

Comment: http://pythontutor.ru

Answer (score 4):

Результат любого сравнения возвращает `True` или `False`.

```
1 == 1 = True
1 > 1 = False
```

Представь, что в условие вместо сравнения, ты сразу вставила результат сравнения

```
if True:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

Этот пример **всегда** будет выводить True

Answer (score 4):

`True` и `False` это константы логического типа `bool`
[Built-in Constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#False).

`True` это истина.

`False` это ложь.

Оператор `if` выполняет оценку выражения правой части в логическом контексте [if statement](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement).
Полный синтаксис оператора выглядит так:

```
if expression:
    (блок кода оператора if)
elif expression: # допускается больше 1 elif
    (блок кода оператора elif)
else:
    (блок кода оператора else)
```

Обязательной частью является только блок `if`. Так же операторы такие как `if` часто называют операторами ветвления.

Пример работы:

```
yellow = "red"   # теперь эти переменные
blue = "orange"  # будут возвращать
brown = "brown"  # присвоенные им значения

if yellow == "yellow": # здесь не сработает yellow ≠ "yellow" (False)
    print "yes yellow"
elif blue == "blue": # здесь не сработает blue ≠ "blue" (False)
    print "yes blue"
elif brown == "brown": # это выражение пройдёт проверку brown = "brown" (True)
    print "yes brown" # это будет напечатано
else: 
   print "without success" # блок else не сработает т.к. сработало одно из условий выше
```